# How can I prevent exposing the complete website to unauthenticated visitors in Meteor.js & Blaze?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

Meteor always pushes the complete source code with all templates to the client and you can restrict data access by user authentication.

BUT **is there a way to reveal the complete website only to authenticated users**, and not to visitors? (**Dynamically template loading from server**)

As I remember, it was possible to load templates dynamically with Meteor.js and Angular.js but I haven´t found anything about Blaze!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to do that? Is protecting the data not enough?

Comment: @LionC For example if you have a private project under a public domain, which is used by just a few people and you don´t want to reveal anything about the project at all, just a login form

Comment: Then I'd make it simple and just hide the whole application under authentication of the login form and exclude that from the application.

Comment: @LionC but this addresses exactly the problem of loading templates dynamically from server after the user has logged in, or how would you hide it?

Comment: You could just have a login form that has nothing to do with your angular application. Or you could make the templates load as needed (by using `templateUrl`) and make the server protect them with authentication.

Comment: But how can I prevent accessing the application url directly? Maybe nginx with htaccess-like protection is the right way to go...

Comment: FYI, the [**upcoming release 1.5**](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/8327) is going to ship with _dynamic module imports_, which would gracefully help in your case. With it you can forbid the server from sending selective source to unauthenticated users. That being said, unauthenticated users can be restricted to have completely zero chance to peek sensitive source. Extremely exciting!

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic imports that loads templates after authentication.